# Coupon expiration date not working

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, date

In Magento CE 1.9.2.4 I use an extension who creates coupons for birthdays in a "Shopping Cart Price Rule". These coupon are generated with an expiration date.
The coupon works except that Magento does not check the expiration date.

Is it normal or do I have something not correctly configured ?

Today the only solution I have is to delete manually the expired coupons...

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem:
 - check if there is a cron in your server that call cron.php every 2 minutes
 - check if datetime of your server is correct and correctly printed from Magento